# Converting order by case to Linq statement

Tags: linq

I have a query such as;

```
select * from TABLE_DEF_ROLE order by case when RoleName = 'Select All' then 0 else 1 end, RoleName
```

I have checked the related questions and answers but still couldn't figure it out. How would I translate it into a linq statement?

Comment: What have you tried so far with LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var roles = from r in db.Roles
        orderby r.RoleName == "Select All" ? 0 : 1 descending
        select r;
```

(`Roles` entity refers to your table)